# Golang: Remove AMQP binding without knowing the RoutingKey

Tags: go, amqp

I have a application that has a list of 'IDs' to create bindings for. So for example:

Input: `1,2,3,4`
Bindings created (from exchange `foo` to queue `bar`):

```
foo -> 1 -> bar
[..]
foo -> 4 -> bar
```

Then I remove an item (`4`) from my list/input and restart my application. The `bar` queue is durable (and must stay that way) and now I'd like the binding for `4` to be remove. But: how do I do that?

There is a queueUnbind method (https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rabbitmq/amqp091-go#Channel.QueueUnbind) but that requires me to know the routingKey (`4`) in order to remove the binding. In this case I do not have state so I don't know what (if any) items are gone and therefore what binding(s) to remove.

I can also delete the `bar` queue and then recreate it with all 'current' bindings. But that could cause messages to be destroyed that might still be on that queue. I also cannot remove the `foo` exchange as that is used by others.

Without introducing any state in my service: how can I remove the bindings I no longer require?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the desired bindings, what you could do is the following:

- rebuild the queue/queue-subscriptions on startup, this way you will know for sure that everything is set up the way you want. This also means that you will remove/recreate the bindings, so you may miss some messages.

A better approach would probably be the following:

- When your application starts/restarts, try to 'recreate' the bindings, without recreating the queue. This way you are certain the required bindings are there. ( https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rabbitmq/amqp091-go#Channel.QueueBind)
- When you receive a delivery, you can inspect the routingkey of the Delivery object (as seen here: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rabbitmq/amqp091-go#Delivery) . Don't want this routing key? Either Ack or Nack the packet, and remove the binding at this stage. This way your application will automatically correct 'wrong' bindings as they pop up.

That way your application won't have to store a file with bindings (i.e. state), and will automatically correct when old/unwanted bindings show up.

You could also Reject any messages that have a routing key that you do not recognize, let them be sent to a dead-letter queue and add a handler that will automatically remove the bindings from there. That way you don't have to modify the bindings in the 'consuming' part of th

Comment: Yes the first one is something we considered but indeed don't want. However the second option might not even be a bad idea. I will discuss it internally, thanks.